# Grails not reading plugin's Config.groovy file

Tags: grails, configuration, log4j, grails-plugin

I have a Grails (2.3.6) app (`myapp`) and a custom plugin (`grails-myapplogging`). I want to:

- Configure log4j in the plugin and nowhere else
- In keeping with the above, this implies that I am omitting any `log4j` closures inside the app's `Config.groovy` file

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2922667/892029), I added a `Config.groovy` file to my plugin and gave it this:

```
println("Well hello!")

log4j {
    appenders {
        appender new org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender(
            name: "appLog",
            datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",
            fileName: "/var/log/myapp.log"
        )
    }

    root {
        error 'stdout', 'appLog'
    }
}
```

Then in my app's `BuildConfig.groovy`, I add the plugin to my project. Then I run the app (`grails run-app`) and expect to see some logging. The app starts up just fine, doesn't throw or print any errors, however `/var/log/myapp.log` never gets created. **Additionally, when building, I never see the "*Well hello!*" message get printed out.** Ideas?

When I take this `log4j` closure and put it into my app's `Config.groovy`, everything works perfectly fine. So this is definitely a situation where the plugin's `Config.groovy` is *not* being read.

**Update:** do I need to manually "include" the plugin's `Config.groovy` somehow, or explicitly tell the app to load it, etc.?

Comment: A plugin's `Config.groovy` is _never_ read when the plugin is included in another application, that's what we've been trying to tell you in comments on your last several questions.

Comment: Ok @IanRoberts (+1) - I appreciate the tip. So where then, inside my plugin, can I put the above `log4j` closure so that I don't need to configure any logging in my app?

Comment: You can't.  There are tricks that a plugin can use to inject default values into the `grailsApplication.config` (see the spring-security-core plugin for an example) but those all happen too late to influence logging - logging is set up by a servlet context listener that loads the application's `Config.groovy`, merge in any `grails.config.locations` externals, and then pull out the log4j closure.  Plugins don't get a look in until after this listener is finished.

Comment: The closest I can think would be if you put a `src/groovy/MyPluginConfig.groovy` in the plugin and then have the app do `grails.config.locations = [MyPluginConfig]`, I can't think of any way to get in early enough to influence logging with absolutely no changes to the host application.

Comment: Thanks @IanRoberts (+2) - if plugins load too early to influence logging like you say, then is there any way to completely disable all the logging, and then add in my own "custom" logging (which would just be log4j!) inside the plugin? Sort of a "drop n' swap" approach?

Comment: You could just do `LogManager.resetConfiguration()` and then run your own `DOMConfigurator`, but that would overwrite the configuration that has already been done by the normal mechanism, it wouldn't prevent that configuration from happening in the first place (so `stacktrace.log` would still be created, for example).  I think the `grails.config.locations = [MyPluginConfig]` option will be the least invasive option that actually works.

Comment: We have an inline plugin called `common` that defines `log4j` in `CommonConfig.groovy` and the logging seems to work just fine. As Ian said, we have a `grails.config.locations = ["classpath:CommonConfig.groovy"]`. Of course, it could be that inline plugins behave differently.