# How to configure log4j for a grails plugin?

Tags: grails, log4j, grails-plugin

Here is my log4j config from my plugin's `Config.groovy`:

```
log4j = {       
    appenders {
        console name: "stdout",
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%c{2} %m%n")
    }

    debug 'grails.app.services'
}
```

I have a service that logs but I am not seeing any logger print on my stdout, just to make sure I used both println and log.info but I am only seeing the println output only.

I have seen this but does not help.

[How do I configure logging for a grails plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920796/how-do-i-configure-logging-for-a-grails-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a log-level and appender for the root logger, which will be used as the defaults for all other loggers. Assuming you want to use error as the default level, and send (append) logs to the console only, do the following:

```
log4j = {       
    appenders {
        console name: "stdout", layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%c{2} %m%n")
    }


    root {
        // by default, log at the ERROR level and send logs to the console
        error 'stdout'
    }

    // override the default level to DEBUG for service classes
    debug 'grails.app.services'
}
```

Comment: If you have the plugin installed in an application, then you need to configure log4j as shown above in the *application*, not the plugin. The plugin's log4j config is ignored when it's installed in an application

Comment: okay good to know, but I added this to the plugin when the log4j config in my application is not working. Btw the application services can log but not the plugin services. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins'
```

Add this code to error in log4j config. And your plugin will be loged.
For example my log4j config:

```
log4j = {
// Example of changing the log pattern for the default console appender:
//
appenders {

    console name: 'stdout', layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%d [%t] %-5p (%c) - %m%n')

}

root {
    info 'stdout', 'file'
    additivity = true
}
error 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins <-You nedd this one
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
        'org.springframework',
        'org.hibernate',
        'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
```

}